# NullReferenceException on Dictionary.Add with dictionary variable not Null, key not Null and no multithreading

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

There have been a number of similar questions here, but none explains what is happening in my case; so here goes.

I have the following (simplified) piece of code:

```
' row is a System.Data.DataRow
' _typeProperties is a Dictionary(Of String, PropertyInfo)

Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
Dim elem As KeyValuePair(Of String, PropertyInfo)
Dim value As Object = Nothing
Try
    For Each elem In _typeProperties
        value = row.Item(elem.Key)
        data.Add(elem.Key, value)       ' NullReferenceException here
    Next
Catch ex As Exception When MyExceptionFilter(ex, data, elem, value)
End Try
```

Sometimes I get a NullReferenceException on the indicated line.  This exception is exceedingly rare and I cannot reproduce it at will.  However, I can modify my application, send it out to a customer and sure enough, after some days it will reproduce on its own.

The call stack is not very helpful:

```
StackTrace: 
  XXX.RowToType(DataRow row) in C:\XXX.vb:line 645.
```

Moreover, as you can see I included an exception filter in the Catch block.  In there I write a minidump (with the call stack of the exception intact).  Here is the relevant portion of the call stack revealed by the minidump:

```
  ...
  App.exe!MyExceptionFilter( ex,  data,  elem,  value) Line 627
  App.exe!RowToType( row) Line 647 + 0x1f bytes
  [External Code]   
  App.exe!RowToType(System.Data.DataRow row) Line 645 + 0x112 bytes
  App.exe!SomeClass.get_Item(Integer index) Line 1141 + 0xe bytes   
  user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()  + 0x23 bytes    
  user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()  + 0x693 bytes   
  ...
```

The exception happens somewhere in the [External Code] block; then the filter of the Catch block gets executed (line 2 & line 1).

At the moment of the exception, these are the values for the three involved variables:

```
  data: Not Nothing; 
  elem: Not Nothing; 
  elem.Value: Not Nothing (Int32 ID)
  elem.Key: Not Nothing
  value: Nothing
```

So there appears to be absolutely no reason for data.Add to throw a NullReferenceException.

As some people suggested in other questions, there might be some threading issue.  However, the dictionary to which I am writing can by definition only be visible to one thread.  (And to be sure, I also checked the minidump to make sure that no thread is executing the same code.)

I might just silently ignore this exception, but I'd rather figure this out.

**Edit.** for those interested, here the whole code:

```
Private Function RowToType(ByVal row As DataRow) As DataSourceRow
    Dim o = _typeActivator({})
    Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim elem As KeyValuePair(Of String, PropertyInfo) = Nothing
    Dim value As Object = Nothing
    Try
        For Each elem In _typeProperties
            value = row.Item(elem.Key)
            If DBNull.Value.Equals(value) Then value = Nothing
            elem.Value.SetValue(o, value, Nothing)
            data.Add(elem.Key, value)           ' NullReferenceException here
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception When RowToTypeExceptionFilter(ex, row, data, elem, value)
    End Try

    o.Data = data
    Return o
End Function
```

FYI: `_typeActivator` creates an instance  `o` of a dynamic type; don't think it has anything to do with the problem though.

Comment: any multi-threading issues regarding `_typeProperties`?

Comment: @JeffRSon: By design there should be none (since the containing object is only known to the UI thread).  Moreover, I checked the Minidump to be absolutely sure no other thread was even near that code (meaning no other thread had even an instance of the class the exception happened in).

Comment: Can you reproduce it on your machine "after a few days"? Or has it ever only happened on that customers machine?

Comment: It has only ever happened on one particular machine at the customer.  Although that bit of code is also executed fairly often, I have never been able to reproduce it while debugging.  I did not try to reproduce it on my machine without debugger or with debugger in release mode (no time).

Comment: When trying to debug, "simplified" code only works if it reproduces the problem....it's kind of worthless to check your sample for a possible NRE when it's never actually thrown an NRE....

Comment: Please double check, are you absolutely sure it is a `NullReferenceException` and not an `ArgumentNullException` or something else?

Comment: So this is just wild conjecture on my part, but given the fact that it only happens on ONE machine at the client, and your debugging turns up no issues, I can't help but wonder what kind of memory constraints the client machine is under.  Is there a scenario where the app is polling the `PropertyInfo` for an object, and then while it's trying to enumerate the dictionary, the underlying reflected object is GC'd, hence causing your disconnect?

Comment: What is line 645 in your code?

Comment: Could it have something to do with `value: nothing`? I don't know the specifics of Object, but if value is actually a reference to row.Item(elem.key) which is nothing, perhaps its causing an issue. Looks like your stack trace is also indicating its an issue with the datarow.

Comment: @MattJohnson: I am 100% sure that it is `System.NullReferenceException`.
@N4TKD: line 645 is the one marked with `NullReferenceException here` in my sample above.  
@MauriceReeves: the property dictionary is built and cached long before this exception occurs.  The memory consumption of the app is somewhat unusually high since it does scanning and ocr.

Comment: @MarkBrackett: agree, the simplification is minor however (two lines removed) and does not affect either `elem.Key`, `value` or `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone else suggested, the line number in the call stack (though consistent between builds) always referred to the wrong line.  The function parameter (`row`) was actually the NULL value.. mystery solved.

Comment: sorry, the delay for attributing them had passed

Answer (score 0):

`value: Nothing` would be a valid reason to get a Null Reference exception.
It's possible that the string in your DataRow is Nothing (if it the column didn't exist, you'd get an exception).

Comment: So why would that cause an exception in data.Add?

Comment: Read slightly wrong. It it possible another thread is editing `_typeProperties`?

Comment: Just because another thread isn't in the same block of code, doesn't mean one of the objects used isn't being touched - you didn't indicate the latter. The concern isn't the object you're writing to, but those that you're reading from.

Comment: I meant the latter; there is no other thread with access to the objects this thread is touching

Comment: value is nothing. That will give you the exception in data.Add because you aren't adding an instance of an object. Your problem here doesn't seem to be the dictionary. If you were to create a test dictionary of string, object and call testdict.Add("test", nothing) you would get the same exception. The problem seems to me to be that row.Item(elem.Key) is null. Why not check for that case before calling data.Add?

Comment: @user2517183: That's not true at all. Values can be null (Nothing). For example, given a `Dictionary<String, String>`, `dict.Add("empty", Nothing)` is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the doco for nothing.

> > When you assign Nothing to an object variable, it no longer refers to any object instance. If the variable had previously referred to an instance, setting it to Nothing does not terminate the instance itself. The instance is terminated, and the memory and system resources associated with it are released, only after the garbage collector (GC) detects that there are no active references remaining.

Is is possible that the system believes the object to have a valid reference prior to the setting of it to "Nothing".

This could occur outside the setting of dictionary value, or inside the dictionary itself. The objects linked to the keys might be released it is set.

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful to validate the content of the object to be added, it may be DBNull.

```
' row is a System.Data.DataRow'
' _typeProperties is a Dictionary(Of String, PropertyInfo)'
Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, PropertyInfo) In _typeProperties

    'Validates that _typeProperties has no empty or nothing value as key'
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.Key) Then Continue For

    'Validates that the row contains the specified column'
    If Not row.Table.Columns.Contains(pair.Key) Then Continue For

    data.Add(pair.Key, If(IsDBNull(row(pair.Key)), "", row(pair.Key)))
    'data.Add(pair.Key, CheckNull(Of String)(row(pair.Key)))'
Next
```

---

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Evaluates the entry parameter to <c>DBNull</c>, and returns the default value of data type
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <typeparam name="T">Generic Type</typeparam>
    ''' <param name="Value">Object to evaluate</param>
    ''' <returns>If Value contains data, returns the value casted, otherwise returns the default value of type</returns>
    Public Shared Function CheckNull(Of T)(ByVal Value As Object) As T
        If Value Is Nothing OrElse System.Convert.IsDBNull(Value) Then
            If GetType(T) = GetType(String) Then
                Return DirectCast(DirectCast(String.Empty, Object), T)
            End If
        Else
            Return DirectCast(Value, T)
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: The first validation (that "typeProperties has no empty or nothing value as key") is not necessary; a dictionary does not allow NULL keys.  The second validation (that "the row contains the specified column") might be sensible, but this is satisfied by construction, and most importantly: this is not where the exception gets thrown!  The third point (testing for DBNull) is also not necessary, since DBNull.Value can be cast to Object which is the type of the Dictionary values.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is right here, row.Item(elem.Key), elem.key does not exist and it is what is throwing the null exception. You can check for the column by checking row.Table.Columns.Contains(elem.key).

Comment: nope, I am certain that the exception happens on the line after that

Comment: @Andreas compiler optimization may be at play here, I have seen it give incorrect line numbers for errors. I feel that is what is happening here, I would check and make sure the columns exist and see what happens.

Comment: you're right.  In anticipation of such a problem, I already modified my code by inserting one try/catch block per line; haven't pushed it out to a customer yet though.